# Separating JLayeredPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, separator, jlayeredpane

I have a set of panels across a layered pane. I need a separator between to separate the sideBar from the topBar and the tabbedPanel. I left a buffer of 10 pixels for it to be placed. unfortunately, possibly due to it being a JLayeredPane, I canot get it to view.

Is there a way to define the separator's X location? as this should solve it. Either way, here's a sample of the code, which I've removed most information from.

Alternatively, offer a different solution entirely, so long as I can get a defined split from the sideBar and other two panels. I've already tried to apply the BorderLayout.WEST to the sideBar, but due to it being a JLayeredPane, it gives me errors.

```
lPane = new JLayeredPane();
lPane.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 768);

calendarFrame = new JFrame ("Calendar Frame");
calendarFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
calendarFrame.setLayout(null);

//Prepare side bar
sideBar = new JPanel ();
sideBar.setLayout(null);
sideBar.setBounds(0, 0, 210, 768);

//Prepare top bar
topBar = new JPanel ();
topBar.setLayout(null);
topBar.setBounds(220, 0, 774, 50);

//Create tabbed pane
tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setBounds(220, 50, 774, 700);
//Tab code here, but not needed for questuion

calendarFrame.add(lPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
lPane.add(sideBar, new Integer(0), 0);
lPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
lPane.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
lPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
lPane.add(topBar, new Integer(1), 0);
lPane.add(tabbedPane, new Integer(2), 0);
```

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

if you want to create fixed 10pixels gap,

you can use

- [EmptyBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) (or [CompoundBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#custom))
- [BorderLayout(int horizontalGap, int verticalGap)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout%28int,%20int%29) or [GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

just my curiosity are you ...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class EditableListExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public EditableListExample() {
        super("Editable List Example");
        String[] data = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};
        JList list = new JList(data);
        JScrollPane scrollList = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollList.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
        Box listBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        listBox.add(scrollList);
        listBox.add(new JLabel("JList"));
        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        Vector<String> dummyHeader = new Vector<String>();
        dummyHeader.addElement("");
        dm.setDataVector(strArray2Vector(data), dummyHeader);
        JTable table = new JTable(dm);
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollTable.setColumnHeader(null);
        scrollTable.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
        Box tableBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        tableBox.add(scrollTable);
        tableBox.add(new JLabel("JTable"));
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        c.add(listBox);
        c.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
        //c.add(new JLabel("test"));
        //c.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));
        c.add(tableBox);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private Vector<Object> strArray2Vector(String[] str) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>();
            v.addElement(str[i]);
            vector.addElement(v);
        }
        return vector;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final EditableListExample frame = new EditableListExample();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```